# Flow thinks that PropTypes is unreachable

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, react-proptypes

I try to add propTypes to my component, but flow shows message "[flow coverage] uncovered code". I already have installed flow-typed for PropTypes, it also doesn't help. I have no idea what is wrong.

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

type Props = {
    name: string
}

class Hello extends Component<Props> {
    static propTypes = { // [flow coverage] uncovered code
        name: PropTypes.string
    }

    render() {
        return <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>;
    }
}
```

[flow warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fdbK.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help us help you, please provide your code as actual text content, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [`flowtype/flow-for-vscode#138`](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode/issues/138), this is a bug in `flow coverage` (issue: [`facebook/flow#2233`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2233)).